# Insert am document at index in Meteor Collection

Tags: collections, indexing, meteor

i need to replace an elements in an Meteor.Collection, but want to replace it, so it appears in the same position as the old one.

For that i found in the docs in `observe`, that there is an `atIndex` parameter in the callbacks.

e.g.

```
cursor.observe({
   addedAt: function(document, atIndex, before){
      ...
   }
   ...
})
```

does this mean i can insert objects at a specific index position, if so how?

Comment: You can add 'created' field for example and just copy old 'created' values to new object and delete old after that. I believe this is a more flexible way for collection sorting.

Comment: this is the approach i\m taking now, adding a `_index` field with an increasing number.
But As the atIndex already exists, it make sense to use this one i guess

Answer (score 1):

If you use [.update()](http://docs.meteor.com/#update) it will appear in the same position.

Or maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: thats right, but the id will change to but i can't change the id, when using update. or not?

Comment: Why would you want to change the _id? The _id won't change when you use .update().

Comment: the id can be dependent on something, so i generate my own hex ids.

Comment: So i ask myself, for what is the `atIndex` at all, if i can't set it myself somewhere? Do in have to know about then?